# request Fullscreen does not work on Android Stock browser

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-api, html5-video

I have my own HTML5 video player and my problem is I can't enter Fullscreen on Android Stock Browser (tested on Huawei ascend mate, htc desire, galaxy s2/s3). It works on another browsers(Chrome, Safari etc). I opened Youtube with Android stock browser and there no problems with this option. I noticed there isn't youtube player, but another standart player.

```
window.onload=function(){
var video = document.getElementById("video-player");

function enterFullscreen() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {          
        if (video.requestFullscreen) {
            video.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
            video.msRequestFullscreen();                
        } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            video.mozRequestFullScreen();               
        } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            video.webkitRequestFullscreen();                
        }           
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
    return false;
}


var rF = document.getElementById("fullscreen-btn");
rF.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enterFullscreen();
});
};

<video id="video-player" width="640" height="390" src="video.mp4" controls></video>
<button id="fullscreen-btn" type="button">Fullcsreen</button>
```

Comment: can you specify which Android version and the devices you are testing on? some of the players when unable to go into full screen mode will stretch the video to the full browser view to create a fullscreen like experience

Comment: Ok, i tested on huawei ascend mate, htc desire, Samsung galaxy s2/s3

Comment: check video.js requestFullscreen method, if the device doesn't support it they stretch the video to the full viewport you may need to do the same.
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/e5595b1e38d0aa7c26bb2494e95995afe8ab83e9/src/js/player.js

Comment: JWPlayer has a page with fullscreen support status http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/fullscreen/ you can see that the Android stock browser doesn't support it